# Keep values from the beforepost event to the afterpost event

Tags: delphi, events, delphi-2007

I am writing this question for Delphi 2007, but I'm pretty sure that this is a common problem in all kind of languages.

So, I have a project where I need to keep informations about the old and new value of certain fields (which are given in the BeforePost event of the dataset I'm working with) and use them in the AfterPost event.

For now, I have been using global variables, but there is already so many of them in the project that this is becoming a real issue when it comes to managing documentation and/or comments.

Basically, I am asking if there is a better way (in Delphi 2007 or in general) to keep the informations from the BeforePost event of a Dataset and get them back in the AfterPost event.

Comment: No. That won't be possible (of course it depends on the `TDataSet` descendant's implementation, but by meaning no). Between those events dataset flushes field buffers and refreshes itself with the new posted state, so the previous state should be lost.

Comment: What kind of TDataSet are you using?  Reason I ask is that this kind of stuff gets a lot simpler if you happen to be using TClientDataSets.

Comment: Btw, what I said wasn't meaning to contradict @TLama.  It's just that temporary TClientDataSets provide very handy ways of preserving dataset data between events occurring on your main dataset...  +1 for the interesting q, btw.

Comment: Using a derived class of you dataset class you might implement a property AlddDataDataset for  keeping a "Memory" Dataset (e.g. TAdodataset or Clientdateset) which would be created by cloning AfterOpen and fed BeforePost.

Comment: ClientDataSets make use of their fields' 'OldValue', 'NewValue'...

Comment: Why not save the old values to a log table during the beforepost event?

Comment: What code are you executing in AfterPost event? The reason I'm asking you this is that maybe you could move all that code into BeforePost event itself during which you have both old and new values available.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for all the answers! Basically, I need to update a detail dataset AFTER my master dataset has been posted (to ensure that the data is in the database). My detail dataset has 2 key fields that comes from my master dataset so if I want to update the detail and change the key values, I need to keep the old values from the beforepost event.

Comment: @JohnEasley This is actually a good idea that I'm gonna talk about to my project manager.!

Comment: The easiest solution is to go ahead and insert the row into your detail dataset, but don't post the changes. In the AfterPost event of the master dataset, you can check for the state of the detail dataset being dsInsert and do the detail post then. If the master table change is cancelled, you simply cancel the insert into the detail table.

Answer (score 1):

first create a new Custom Data Source

```
  TDataRecord = array of record
    FieldName: string;
    FieldValue: Variant;
  end;

  TMyDataSource = class(TDataSource)
  private
    LastValues: TDataRecord;
    procedure MyDataSourceBeforePost(DataSet: TDataSet);
    procedure SetDataSet(const Value: TDataSet);
    function GetDataSet: TDataSet;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    function GetLastValue(FieldName: string): Variant; 
    property MyDataSet: TDataSet read GetDataSet write SetDataSet;
  end;

{ TMyDataSource }

constructor TMyDataSource.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
end;

destructor TMyDataSource.Destroy;
begin
  SetLength(LastValues, 0);
  inherited Destroy;
end;

function TMyDataSource.GetDataSet: TDataSet;
begin
  Result := DataSet;
end;

procedure TMyDataSource.SetDataSet(const Value: TDataSet);
begin
  DataSet := Value;
  DataSet.BeforePost := MyDataSourceBeforePost;
end;

procedure TMyDataSource.MyDataSourceBeforePost(DataSet: TDataSet);
var
  i: integer;
begin
  SetLength(LastValues, DataSet.FieldCount);
  for i:=0 to DataSet.FieldCount-1 do
  begin
    LastValues[i].FieldName := DataSet.Fields.Fields[i].FieldName;
    LastValues[i].FieldValue := DataSet.Fields.Fields[i].OldValue;
  end;
end;

function TMyDataSource.GetLastValue(FieldName: string): Variant;
var
  i: integer;
begin
  Result := Null;
  for i:=0 to Length(LastValues)-1 do
    if SameText(FieldName, LastValues[i].FieldName) then
    begin
      Result := LastValues[i].FieldValue;
      break;
    end;
end;
```

and after override application Data Source

```
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  private
    MyDataSource: TMyDataSource;
  end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ADOQuery1.Active := true;
  MyDataSource := TMyDataSource.Create(Self);
  MyDataSource.MyDataSet := ADOQuery1;
  DBGrid1.DataSource := MyDataSource;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MyDataSource.Free;
end;

procedure TForm1.ADOQuery1AfterPost(DataSet: TDataSet);
var
  AValue: Variant;
begin
  AValue := MyDataSource.GetLastValue('cname');
  if not VarIsNull(AValue) then;
end;
```

Comment: Hello @AngelsGR! Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately, since this is a bit of an old topic for me, I can't even test it. I changed job and no longer use Delphi. Perhaps someone else than me could validate that this is working! I can't mark this as the answer for now.

Comment: ops, i didn't see that you make this question before 10 months!!